# Running own executable on Android shell

Tags: terminal

I need a specific command line tool and I have made a C program in my Linux shell. I have compiled the program with an ARM cross-compiler. I have then moved the program into the Android file system and tried to run it.

The output is permission denied.

What do I have to do, in order to run my own compiled programs in Android file system?

Comment: Tried `chmod +x pgm` and then `./pgm` also?

Comment: Possibly you placed it on your sdcard -- which is mounted with the `noexec` flag. You either need to move it into the phone's internal storage, or run it via a shell (e.g. `sh /path/to/myexecutable`).

Comment: [How to compile C into an executable binary file and run it in Android from Android Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868309/how-can-i-run-c-binary-executable-file-in-android-from-android-shell)

Answer (score 22):

I assume that you used adb push for uploading your executable to the sd-card. Unfortunately the sd-card is always mounted with "noexec" which means that you can't execute anything from here.

Therefore you have to copy the executable to the local filesystem, e.g. to /data/local. In case the device is not rooted or you don't have BusyBox installed there will be no "cp" command. You can simply use cat: `cat /sdcard/myprog > /data/local/myprog`.

Then you have to set the executable permission on the executable. Chmod on android usually does not support the "u+x" syntax. Therefore you have to call `chmod 555 /data/local/myprog`.

Afterwards you can execute your executable: `/data/local/myprog`.

Alternatively the directory `/data/local/tmp` can be used. Via adb shell you have full access in this directory. On modern devices (Android 11+) apps can't list files from this directory, but they are still able to execute executables from there if you provide the full path of the executable.

**Update**: On Android 10+, apps that has a targetSDK of 29 or higher can no longer execute anything that is located in their app private directory: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission

Comment: Thx for your reply. In fact the problem was on the binary generation. It was not being generated correctely! ;)

Comment: I have busybox on my device, but this command: `shell@n200C:/ $ busybox cp /storage/external_storage/sda1/ffmpeg /data/  ------ show error= cp: can't create '/data/ffmpeg': Permission denied`

Comment: `tmp-mksh: /data/local/workspace/clang+llvm-5.0.0-aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/clang++: No such file or directory` though the file is present

Comment: `/data/local` requires root access on my device. Use `/data/local/tmp` instead

Answer (score 18):

First, you have to push it into a directory, such as `/data/local/tmp`. Then, you have to set permission for that using `chmod 755 executable`. After that, you can run it as `./executable`.

Complete steps are as follows:

```
adb push executable /data/local/tmp
adb shell
cd /data/local/tmp
chmod 755 executable
./executable
```

Alternatively, if you want to run it from your asset folder, you have to copy the file to your data folder `/data/data/packagename/`. Then using `File` class, set the `setExecutable` flag to `true` for the file and run it by the Process class or third party packages like *Root Tools* .

**UPDATE**
if you are targeting sdk 29 or higher you CANNOT use the binary from your asset folder ! you have to copy your binary to jnilib folder then run it from native library directory ! `context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir`