# How can run native executables compiled for ARM on unrooted Android devices?

Tags: adb, shell, terminal, command-line, arm-processors

Following [this](https://www.acmesystems.it/arm9_toolchain) tutorial I have compiled a *Hello World!* ARM binary from C source using `gcc`.
I want to run this program on my unrooted Android phone but I can't figure out an easy way to do it.

What I've tried:

1. Copying `hello` to `/sdcard` and trying to run it from there. This doesn't work because the internal storage is mounted with the `noexec` flag.
2. Copying `hello` to `/data/local/` using `cp hello /data/local/` or `cat hello > /data/local/hello` as [explained here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/45564/56754). This also doesn't work and I get a "permission denied" error.
3. Installing a terminal emulator program such as [Termux](https://termux.com/) and using the Termux app to copy `hello` from `/sdcard/hello` to `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`, running `chmod +x hello` and then running `./hello` from the Termux home directory **within the Termux app**. This works but is not a feasible solution.

Is there a better/easier way to run native ELF executables on an unrooted Android phone directly through ADB and doesn't involve installing any apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In addition to `noexec` mount option, `/sdcard` is [emulated](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) filesystem with fixed file permissions. So files can't be set executable. But some file explorers like MiXplorer support executing binaries/scripts from `/sdcard` through `/system/bin/sh`.
2. `/data/local` has permissions `0751`, owner `root.root` <sup>[1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/rootdir/init.rc#448)</sup>, so normal apps can't access it. However from `adb shell` use `/data/local/tmp` which has user/group owner `2000` (aid_shell) <sup>[2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/rootdir/init.rc#473)</sup> and selinux is also allowed <sup>[3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r34/public/shell.te#25)</sup>. So you won't get permission denied.
3. If you don't want to use PC, terminal emulator is the only option. On Termux you can also add `/data/local/tmp` (or a subdirectory) to `$PATH` by editing `~/.profile` if you want to avoid placing binaries on multiple locations. But the directory should be world-readable and selinux must not be denying the access or execution of binaries.